# Unable to git rebase following branch contribution from another user

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

I am having an issue rebasing the main development branch `master` onto my feature branch `crm-feature`.

I am attempting to do this using the normal method of `git rebase master crm-feature`

When I do this I find that I get to a certain point in the rebase when *every* commit becomes a conflict.

Looking at the list of commits in Github I see all *my* commits (authored by me) and then commits from others then all my commits seem to be recreated for some reason. All these commits show like this:

[image]

So from newest at the top to oldest my commit log looks like this:

- Commit from other contributor piccolax00
- Commit from other contributor piccolax00
- All my authored commits with the piccolax00 user committing them like the image above
- Commits from other contributors
- My original commits

So to summarise, I don't understand where the commits have come from by the piccolax00 user and how I can work around them as they seem to be the thing preventing me from rebasing my branch onto `master`. The branch was worked on whilst I was on holiday and before I left all my commits were sitting at the top as I was rebasing onto `master` periodically to give me the latest code from the main dev branch whilst replaying my work on the top every time.

I'm unsure if the branch has been rebased by the piccolax00 user already and what my options would be if that's the case?

Comment: Haven't taken a close look, but at first glace, it looks like someone might have pushed rewritten shared history, thus the conflicts. Also, if these repos are public, can you share the links so that people can take a look directly?

Comment: @Cupcake Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately the repo isn't public otherwise I absolutely would have shared the link. Would it suggest that the piccolax00 user has rebased or something similar? What can I do to allow me to rebase onto `master` now? The commits (authored by me) made by piccolax00 are essentially duplicates.

Comment: So the fact that your commits show up as authored by you but "commited" by the other user does suggest that they were "re-committed" by the other user (via a rebase, cherry-pick, other-history-rewrite-method, etc). Although the commit contents will be the same, the sha hash ID will not be, so as far as git would be concerned, it thinks that they are different commits. I'm trying to think about what you can do...

Comment: Also, have you actually gotten in touch with this other user and tried to figure out with them what happend?

Comment: I can take an educated *guess* at a solution for your problem, but without understanding *exactly* what happened, and without knowing precisely what the states of your repos are, I cannot guarantee you that this will actually solve your problem.

Comment: @Cupcake Yes, I have checked with the other user and they are not 100% sure what happened. Feel free to offer solutions as i'm not sure of the best course of action.

Comment: Look for "recovering from upstream rebase".  Git's new(ish, 2.0 or so) `--fork-point` computation is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this up as I ended up being advised to take a slightly different approach from the one that @Cupcake has provided above. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

In terms of commands I done the following:

```
# made a backup of the branch incase I screw it up during the rebase
git checkout -b crm-feature-branch-original crm-feature-branch

# Rebase my branch onto master and replay my commits on top
git rebase -i crm-feature-branch master
```

During the interactive rebase I then **deleted** the lines with the commits that have been duplicated. I could tell which commits to remove, and not `pick`, by looking at the hashes in Github.

I had some conflicts, however they were expected not anywhere near the same amount I had initially.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take an educated guess at how to solve your problem, given the information provided.

**WARNING:** this solution involves rewriting the history of your repositories, which could potentially result in data loss if you're not careful. **Make backups of your repository before you proceed.**

The simplest way to make a backup repo in Git is to simply clone another local repo, and restore from that backup if something goes wrong.

## (Possibly) the State of the Repositories

From your description, it seems like the state of your repository and your collaborator's looks something like this:

```
# Collaborator history
aaa - ooo - AAA - bb

# Your history
aaa - ccc
```

Where

1. `a` represents your commits,
2. `o` represents commits from other users,
3. `A` represents your rewritten commits (based of the previous `a` commits),
4. `b` represents piccolax00's commits, and
5. `c` represents your new commits that you haven't pushed to the shared upstream repo yet.

## One Solution

Assuming the above is true, and also that the commits `o` haven't been rewritten (i.e. `A`s are the only rewritten commits), then one solution you could use is to reconstruct a correct history using hard resets and selective rebasing of pieces of the histories.

#### Splicing your collaborator's branch

First we'll splice out the `A` commits from your local copy of your collaborator's branch (we'll call it `piccolax00`),

1. Begin my creating a branch `newBase` at the most recent `o` commit in the history, as well as a branch `oldBase` at the most recent `A` commit,

   ```
   git checkout piccolax00
   git branch newBase o
   git branch oldBase A
   ```
2. Next, rebase the series of `b` commits onto the `newBase` branch (i.e., the `o` commits),

   ```
   git rebase --onto newBase oldBase piccolax00
   ```

   You may need to re-resolve conflicts that may occur.

After you have executed the above, and assuming that any conflicts have been resolved with no trouble, then your collaborator's `piccolax00` branch will look like this,

```
aaa - ooo - bb
```

As a sanity check, it is also a good idea to diff this new history against the old one with

```
git diff piccolax00@{1}
```

where `piccolax00@{1}` refers to the state of the `piccolax00` branch before you executed the rebase. If the state of the code at the tip of `piccolax00` and `piccolax00@{1}` are identical, then the rebase has not introduced any errors into the code.

#### Splicing your new commits on top

Theoretically, the earlier steps we executed restored the "correct" history for your upstream branch, so executing a normal rebase should bring your branch into sync with it,

```
git checkout crmpicco
git rebase piccolax00
```

Then your history would look like this,

```
aaa - ooo - bb - ccc
```

You would then need to force-push this new history to your upstream, since you've rewritten quite a lot of commits, so that they no longer have the same sha IDs that they used to.

**WARNING:** be very careful about force-pushing rewritten shared history. If any of your other collaborators have already added commits to the older shared history that piccolax00 pushed, then *they'll* need to bring their own local versions of the shared history in sync with whatever you're pushing as well (probably via more rebases).

This is why rewriting shared history is so often frowned upon, it can be time-consuming for a project's contributors to recover from it if it's done improperly.

Regardless, if you are certain that you want to proceed with pushing the rewritten shared history, then execute

```
git push -f upstream crmpicco
```

where `upstream` is the remote shared repo, and `crmpicco` is the branch that you want to push.

## Other Solutions

It's entirely possible that the above solution does not solve your problem. I can't really help you any further without more info, but if you're stuck, you could do as [torek suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903169/unable-to-git-rebase-following-branch-contribution-from-another-user?noredirect=1#comment53635512_32903169) and investigate whether or not [`--fork-point`](http://jk.gs/git-rebase.html) would help you,

> Look for "recovering from upstream rebase". Git's new(ish, 2.0 or so) --fork-point computation is helpful.

## Additional Resources

- [Jan Krüger's mirror of the official Git documentation](http://jk.gs/git.html)

Comment: Wow, this is a very impressive and well thought out answer. I do have some questions, though. The piccolax00 user was committing to my branch, let's call it `crm-feature-branch` locally and then pushing back to the repo. I have to admit I am slightly confused by the branch names you are using here (puppy, kitty, piglet). It's difficult to understand which is referring to which.

Comment: @crmpicco sorry about the confusing names. I'll take another look at the problem tomorrow and see if I can help clear things up. Brain needs sleep, lol.

Comment: Don't worry about it, thanks for taking the time to help here. It certainly gives me something to think about, however i'm still not sure how to tackle it practically. Your `a o A b c` commit lineage is spot on, however it's the rest of it i'm not certain on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @crmpicco because of the names I used, right? Or are there other things that you're also uncertain of?

Comment: Yes, mainly the names. It's difficult to see where to start.

Comment: @crmpicco is it just you two who are working on that feature branch?

Comment: Yes, there are other commits from others in this branch but these have been brought in through rebasing onto `master` at various times. So, yes it's just `crmpicco` (me) and `piccolax00`.

Comment: Feel free to shoot me an email at crmpicco@aol.co.uk . SO is giving me the "avoid extended discussions" warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91184/discussion-between-cupcake-and-crmpicco).

Comment: @crmpicco I've updated my answer with clearer branch names, hopefully that makes everything clearer. I can't afford to spend anymore time on this, sorry. You have an upvote on the question, so that will help get it some attention. Good luck!

Comment: @crmpicco hi, were you able to resolve your problem with Git?

Comment: Yes, I did get to the bottom of the Git issue. I'll post up my answer to show what I ended up doing. I'd like to say thanks for taking the time to reply to me initially and the follow up with this big write up that certainly helped me and I hope helps others in the future. Credit to SO (thumbs up) ;)